# In a Tycho build, how do I add a timestamp style qualifier when I don't have the .qualifier text added to my version in my MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have a Tycho build project that successfully builds a feature and its bundles as well as a p2 repository.  Everything is built using .qualifier and -SNAPSHOT.  For example:

My MANIFEST.MF file in my bundle is has the version of the bundle set to something like ...

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.3.qualifier
```

My feature is also has its version set to ...

```
<feature version="1.0.3.qualifier"
         id="com.myurl.my.feature"
         label="My Feature"
         provider-name="My Company">
```

My pom.xml file has its version set like so...

```
<version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

This all works great.  The resulting bundles have the qualifier replaced with the standard timestamp, and the resulting built manifest file's version looks like this...

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.3.201402101829
```

The resulting plugin jar file has a name as such as...

```
com.myurl.mybundle.1.0.3.201402101829.jar
```

My artifacts that get deployed to my Maven repository have the -SNAPSHOT

```
1.0.3-SNAPSHOT
```

What I want to do is change my version numbers from using .qualifier and -SNAPSHOT at release time so that I can deploy to my Maven repository a bundle that doesn't have a -SNAPSHOT associated with it.

I use this command to change my version numbers...

```
org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:set-version -DnewVersion=1.0.3
```

After I execute this command, I run my maven build, and the resulting artifacts now have version numbers that don't have the .qualifier and -SNAPSHOT, which is what I expect.

But... What I would like to do is have the resulting bundles have a timestamp as they did when I was using the .qualifier, but I want the artifacts that are deployed to my Maven repository to not have the -SNAPSHOT modifier.  Is this possible using some thing like the ...

```
-DforceContextQualifier
```

... thats availabe in the tycho-packaging-plugin?  If so, how?

Comment: You probably want this currently missing feature: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382482

Comment: Thanks for the info, Tobias.  The hardest part of this bug seems to be coming up with a solution that everyone can agree on.  Is there anything I can do to help?

Comment: There is only one solution proposed - the only dispute is whether people want the solution or rather not want it. If you are in favour, [vote for the bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=382482#vote_382482).

Comment: I added my vote to the bug.  Thanks again.